# How BOBJ stores exported universe

Tags: business-objects, repository

How **Business Objects** store the universe that has been exported?

As far as I understand, **BOBJ** keeps metadata in the repository database and the actual universe (classes, classes, relations) in the files in **FileStore** directory. Is that right?

Could someone please clarify what exactly is kept in metadata in repository DB and in particular is there a field with the actual location of the files in FileStore?

I'm also interested if there is a way to somehow view these files where BOBJ stores the exported universe? For example, sometimes I badly need to figure out whether the object in universe was just changed or deleted and recreated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Business Objects has a repository that contains users, security and reference pointers to the Business Objects content such as reports and universes. This is held in a proprietary format.

The actual reports and universes are stored in the input file store, the location of which can be seen in the server properties of the input file server in the Central Management Console (CMC)

In the CMC, you can also see the file location of the universes and the reports by reviewing their properties

regards

James